# Code improvement, Python the hard way ex48

Tags: python, python-2.7, try-except

I completed the exercise after much confusion and made this code which complies with his tests.

```
WORD_TYPES = {
   'verb' : ['go', 'kill', 'eat'],
   'direction' : ['north', 'south', 'east', 'west'],
   'noun' : ['bear', 'princess'],
   'stop' : ['the','in','of']
} 

def scan(sentance):
    listy = []
    counter = 0
    for word in sentance.split():
        try:
            count = counter
            for key, value in WORD_TYPES.iteritems():
                for ind in value:
                    if ind == word:
                        counter += 1
                        listy.append((key,ind))
            if count == counter:
                raise KeyError
        except KeyError:
            try:
                value = int(word)
                listy.append(('number',value))
            except ValueError:
                listy.append(('error',word))
    return listy
```

The author wanted us to use try and excepts, but I don't feel like I used them efficiently. What is a better way to use them here? Also, when are try and excepts actually ideal? Any other tips for improving the code are also welcomed.

Comment: Should be possibly moved in Code Review http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will assume you are referring to the exercise in http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex48.html

The author says to use `try` and `except` to "cheat" at interpreting numbers because, generally, the common way to do it would be to use regular expressions. Using the `int()` function to attempt to convert an unknown words into int, you can interpret failure as a decent indicator that it is not a number - hence catching the `ValueError` exception.

Your other use of exceptions was unnecessary.

> The try-except construct is only used for handling exceptions that modules can throw. It should never be used as an alternative to if-else.

Also, you don't need to run through every element of a list to find a match, just use the `in` operator.

```
if ind in value:
    # Do Stuff
```